# Getting Exec format error using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdfkit

I am getting the following error while trying to implement `pdfkit gem` in Rails 3.

Error:

```
Errno::ENOEXEC in UsersController#download_pdf

Exec format error - C:/Site/generate3/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386 --encoding UTF-8 --page-size A4 --margin-top 0.25in --margin-right 0.1in --margin-bottom 0.25in --margin-left 0.1in --quiet - -
Rails.root: C:/Site/generate3

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `download_pdf'
```

The following are my code files.

> users/index.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <%= link_to "Download pdf",download_pdf_path(:format => 'pdf') %>
</p>
```

> users/download_pdf.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello PDF</h1>
```

> controller/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def download_pdf
        html = render_to_string(:action => "download_pdf.html.erb")
       kit = PDFKit.new(html)
       send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'report.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')

    end
end
```

> pdfkit.rb:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|

  if ["development"].include?(Rails.env)
    #only if your are working on 32bit machine
    config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-i386').to_s
  else
    #if your site is hosted on heroku or any other hosting server which is 64bit
    config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s
  end

  config.default_options = {
    :encoding=>"UTF-8",
    :page_size=>"A4",
    :margin_top=>"0.25in",
    :margin_right=>"0.1in",
    :margin_bottom=>"0.25in",
    :margin_left=>"0.1in",
    :disable_smart_shrinking=> false
  }
end
```

> Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'



gem 'sqlite3'



group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'



  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'



gem 'pdfkit', '~> 0.5.3'
```

Please help me to resolve this error.And also let me to know how can i open this PDF after converting from HTML in different window with small size.I am using Rails 3.2.19 and windows xp in my system.

Comment: Is your wkhtmltopdf in "C:/Site/generate3/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386" folder? You will face same issue which you were facing with wicked_pdf because both gems require wkhtmltopdf path

Comment: @ User123 : Yes,I have created bin folder inside my app and put the required both file inside this.

Comment: Go in rails console and try to open this file.
File.open(Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-i386'))

Comment: @ user123 : i am getting this result  #<File:C:/Site/generate3/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386> after run your command in rails console.

Comment: @ user123 : i am getting that file from this link https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386 and extract the file from bin folder and put this file in my bin folder.

Comment: kit = PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')
pdf = kit.to_pdf
file = kit.to_file('test/pdf')
try to run it in rails console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78783/discussion-between-user123-and-rajat-474).

Answer (score 0):

try this:
config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf').to_s

Comment: @ Sunny : Actually inside bin folder wkhtmltopdf-i386 is present.I run you command but it gave me the following error.

No wkhtmltopdf executable found at C:/Site/generate3/bin/wkhtmltopdf.